# 2-step diffusion equation with Neumann boundary conditions

Tags: differential-equations, numerical-integration, finite-element-method

I want to resolve a PDE model of 2-step 1D heat diffusion equation.

1st step: If 0< t < 60, it has a constant heat flax at x = 0, and has a Neumann boundary conditions at x = 6000.

2nd step: If t >= 60, it as a Neumann boundary conditions at both edge (x = 0, and x = 6000).

The key problem is that I have some trouble when I use the 1st step results as 2nd step initial value. Any suggestions how to fix it? Consider the following code:

[1st step]

```
Needs["NDSolve`FEM`"]

SoD = 100;
Dif = 69340;

deqN = D[u[t, x], t] - Dif*D[u[t, x], {x, 2}] - If[x == 0 , SoD, 0] ==
NeumannValue[-SoD, x == 0] + NeumannValue[0, x == 6000];

ic = u[0, x] == 0;

sol = NDSolveValue[{deqN, ic}, u, {t, 0, 60}, {x, 0, 6000}, Method -> {"MethodOfLines", "SpatialDiscretization" -> {"FiniteElement", 
   "MeshOptions" -> {"MaxCellMeasure" -> {"Length" -> 0.1}}}}];
Plot3D[sol[t, x], {t, 0, 60}, {x, 0, 6000}, PlotRange -> Full, 
PlotStyle -> Automatic]
```

[image]

I sucessfully got a 1st step result, but I cannot use this result in following 2nd step.

[2nd step]

```
deqN2 = D[u2[t, x], t] - Dif*D[u2[t, x], {x, 2}] == 
NeumannValue[0, x == 0] + NeumannValue[0, x == h];
ic2 = u2[0, x] == Evaluate[sol[t, x] /. t -> 0];
sol2 = NDSolveValue[{deqN2, ic2}, u2, {t, 0, 100}, {x, 0, 60000}, Method -> {"MethodOfLines", "SpatialDiscretization" -> {"FiniteElement", "MeshOptions" -> {"MaxCellMeasure" -> {"Length" -> 0.1}}}}];
```

Thank you for your cooperation.

Answer (score 5):

You don't need to separate the problem in two steps :

```
SoD = 100;
Dif = 69340;

deqN = D[u[t, x], t] - Dif*D[u[t, x], {x, 2}]  ==
NeumannValue[If[t<60 ,100, 0], x == 0] + NeumannValue[0, x == 6000];

ic = u[0, x] == 0;

sol = NDSolveValue[{deqN, ic}, u, {t, 0, 160}, {x, 0, 6000},  
Method -> {"MethodOfLines", "SpatialDiscretization" -> {"FiniteElement", 
   "MeshOptions" -> {"MaxCellMeasure" -> {"Length" -> 0.1}}}}];  

Plot3D[sol[t, x], {t, 0, 160}, {x, 0, 6000}, PlotRange -> Full, PlotStyle -> Automatic]
```

[image]

Note

`NeumannValue[If[t<60 ,SoD, 0], x == 0]` doesn't work, though it should be equivalent to `NeumannValue[If[t<60 ,100, 0]`, x == 0], so far I know.

**EDIT**

If you want to conserve `SoD` in the expression `If[t<60 ,SoD, 0]`, you can do :

`With[{SoD=SoD},D[u[t, x], t] - Dif*D[u[t, x], {x, 2}]  ==
NeumannValue[If[t<60 ,SoD, 0], x == 0] + NeumannValue[0, x == 6000]]`

Comment: (+1) While this is what OP requested, I'd like to point out that the hard jump `If[t<60 ,100, 0]` for `t=60` is not 'natural' - such a jump is not observed in nature. One could fade out the 100 to 0 starting at `t=60` and have it decay at some rate. Just a thought.

Comment: @user21 Physically, it's easy to make relatively hard jumps with a (electrical) resistor.

Comment: Yes, that's what I am trying to say. A more accurate model would use a relative hard jump, not an absolute jump. Maybe I'll add a message to `NDSolve` that warns about this. It's a bit like inconsistent initial and boundary conditions.